# Service Fabric Mesh - Doesn't Show Application In Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, r-sf

Am I getting something fundamentally wrong here...

I created a Service Fabric Mesh application in Visual Studio 2017, created 2 services and then tested on my local 5 Mesh Node cluster - worked as expected.

I then created a Service Fabric Cluster in Azure.
Next, I published my app to my Azure Subscription in the same Resource Group as my SF Cluster.
My app gets published fine and I can see the SF Mesh Application in my Azure Subscription, and I can access the services directly via the IP addresses that the Publish process tells me.
However, when I look at the SF Cluster Explorer for the Azure Cluster I created before publishing it doesn't show my Application or Services there?
I only see the services listed under the Mesh Application - but I can't see the public IPs listed anywhere for those services.

What am I missing? The services are clearly working as I can get data back out from them.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I believe you cannot see anything in SF Explorer because it's connected to regular Service Fabric and not your Mesh application which is not running on the Service Fabric cluster you provisioned. I haven't found any information on connecting to SF Explorer for Mesh yet. I expect MS will provide more information in the future. If you want to find the public IP for your Mesh application, try

```
az mesh gateway show -g ResourceGroupName -n GatewayName
```